# Create the same ref functionality in React Function component as in React Class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref, react-ref

I would like to create the exact same behaviour in function component ref as there is in class component ref.

Heres an example:

```
const AnotherComponent = () => {
    const DoSomething () => console.log(something);
    return <div> There is a content </div>;
}

const MyComponent () => {
    let newRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        newRef.current.DoSomething();
    }, []);
    return <AnotherComponent ref={newRef} />;
}
```

I know about forwardRef, but from what I understand it allows you to bind the ref to a specific input to get its events, but not to the WHOLE component with all its functions.

Is it even possible to achieve this with function components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's completely possible. React refs are for more than just getting access to DOMNodes. Use a combination of `React.forwardRef` and the `useImperativeHandle` React hook to forward a React ref to a function component and expose out functions/values.

```
const AnotherComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    doSomething
  }));
  const doSomething () => console.log(something);
  return <div> There is a content </div>;
});
```

...

```
const MyComponent () => {
  const newRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    newRef.current.doSomething();
  }, []);
  return <AnotherComponent ref={newRef} />;
}
```

[Forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

[forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref)

[useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)